# No matching for call to '...' with template C++, OOP

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem with template in C++.

This is the code:

```
//main.cpp
main(){
    gestione_bagagli bag;
    Data da(10,8,1980);
    Proprietario pr("Luca","Verdi",da,"Este",true);
    Viaggio vi("12345","Roma");
    speciale b(20,30,48,30,pr,vi);
    speciale& c=b;
    bag.lug.push_back(b);
}
//gestione_bagagli.h
class gestione_bagagli{
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&,const gestione_bagagli&);
public:
    Lista<bagaglio*> lug;
    gestione_bagagli(){}
    template <class T>
    gestione_bagagli(const Lista<T>&){}
};
//contenitore.h
template<class T>
class Lista{
friend class iteratore;
friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream&, const Lista<T>&);
private:
    class nodo{
    public:
        nodo(){}
        nodo(const T& bag, nodo* p, nodo* n): b(bag),prev(p),next(n){}
        T b;
        nodo* prev;
        nodo* next;
    };
    int n_el;
    nodo* first, *last;
public:
    Lista():first(0),last(0),n_el(0){}
    void push_back(const T& b){
        if(first && last){
            last->next=new nodo(b,last,0);
            last=last->next;
        }else first=last=new nodo(b,0,0);
        n_el++;
    }
};
```

The problem is in the main at bag.lug.push_back(b);
speciale is a derived type, but the problem is in the istantation of the template.
error is " main.cpp:14: error: no matching function for call to 'Lista::push_back(speciale&)' " , where bagaglio is hierarchy's base class.

I know, i need to explicity define function template, but it doesn't work!
I tryed this:

```
bag.lug.push_back <bagaglio*>(b);
```

but is a sintax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing a `speciale` into a list of `bagaglio*`. Unless `speciale` has a conversion operator to pointer to `bagaglio`, that isn't going to happen.

Maybe you wanted to push a pointer to a `speciale`?

```
bag.lug.push_back(&b); //notice the address-of operator
```